# Can anyone explain this strange python turtle occurance?

Tags: python, random

If you don't know, python turtle is an application for helping people learn python.
You are given a python interpreter and an onscreen turtle that you can pass directions to using python.

go(10) will cause the turtle to move 10 pixels
turn(10) will cause it to turn 10 degrees clockwise

now look at this

[image]

code:

```
import random
while(1):
    r = random.randint(1,10)
    go (r)
    r = random.randint(-90,90)
    turn (r)
```

can anyone explain this behavior? Notice the straight line. Is there something wrong with pythons random module?

Comment: Any chance you could post the code as text as well?  The image is more than a little hard to read! :)

Comment: probably the initial turtle position is also *random* (not initialized)

Comment: import random
while(1):
 r = random.randint(1,10)
 go (r)
 r = random.randint(-90, 90)
 turn (r)

Comment: Does it start or end with the random line?  If there is a problem with the initial position/first step in the environment you're using that could cause something like this.

Comment: Eh? go and turn are not a part of the turtle module in my python.
What version are you using? What is the rest of the code?

Answer (score 7):

When debugging a problem like this, it might be worthwhile to print out the value of each instruction as you perform it. Hopefully your turtle environment has a way to print values to some window on the screen. You might do something like this:

```
while(1):
     r = random.randint(1,10)
     print "going:", r
     go (r)
     r = random.randint(-90, 90)
     print "turning:", r
     turn (r)
```

This technique goes by many names, but the one I like is "When in doubt, print more out." Doing this may provide some insight into why your turtle is showing the behaviour you see.

Comment: Even with a solid debugger, this is sometimes the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I am the creator of [PythonTurtle](http://pythonturtle.com).

First of all, I'm really honored to see the first question about it in StackOverflow.

About your question: I tried running the code, and it didn't produce the bug, but since this is involving randomness, I can't really reproduce what happened in your computer.

It seems like a bug, but I can't really guess what is causing it. If this kind of bug happens to you again, preferably when randomness is not involved, I'd appreciate if you'll send me the screenshot and the code snippet. My mail is cool-rr@cool-rr.com.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out the values. Here's a little Python program based on your code snippet that does this:

```
import random
while(1):
  distance = random.randint(1,10)
  angle = random.randint(-90, 90)
  print distance, angle
```

I tried this myself, and at no point does angle "get stuck". I suspect there may be some sort of bug in python turtle, but without trying out in that environment it's hard to say for sure.

Is there a way to ask python turtle for the current angle of the turtle? You may want to print that value out as well.